# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/supervisor/migrate-stdout

Tags: docker, supervisord

I'm running supervisor as non-root inside Docker, my config.:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/null
logfile_maxbytes=0
```

When I start the container, I get the error

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/supervisor/migrate-stdout---supervisor-jxo2nr9k.log'

Because there is no permission to write, which is right. I want a read-only image, I cannot write anything to the disk.

Is possible to tell the supervisor not to write any files? Or better, redirect to stdout/err?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the configuration for the individual program(s) managed by Supervisor to also redirect their stdout and stderr to /dev/stdout and /dev/stderr, respectively.

for example if you have a configuration like this:

```
[program:migrate]
command=your-command
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/migrate-stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/migrate-stderr.log
```

then you should update to this:

```
[program:migrate]
command=your-command
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

so in the end:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
logfile=/dev/null
logfile_maxbytes=0
loglevel=info
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:migrate]
command=your-command
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Comment: This doesn't work on a read-only filesystem, I got the error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/supervisor/migrate-stdout---supervisor-qupxrtld.log'